# No syntax highlighting in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am new to Visual studio code and I have installed the visual studio code on my windows 10 laptop. My source codes are showing in all white text and not showing in different color with syntax highlighting. it is hard to to find my code. The video I watched for training purpose was showing code in different colors.
I have attached screen shots for both windows below; please let me now how to make my codes in color;
My codes are all in white text;
Training video had codes in color;

[image: Version number]

[image: Training video has these colors codes]
[image: My codes are all in white text]

Answer (score 2):

you have to save your file to determine the type of file.
i.e. if it is a python file, you have to save it file_name.py
and then the IDE will know to color the keywords.